# Retrieve all the data from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I want to retrieve all the events that a student has attended by using this student ID number. So this is my PHP code, this code is working but it can only retrieve 1 event while this student has attended several events already.

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$username='tan';
$password='1234567'; 
$db='feedback01';

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);

if (!$conn)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  $studentID=$_POST['StudentID'];

  $studentID=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$studentID);
  $query="SELECT * From PassportData WHERE StudentID='$studentID'";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  $response = array();
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $event = $row["Events"];
        $date = $row["Date"];
        $code = "login_success";
        array_push($response, array("code"=>$code, "Events"=>$event, "Date"=>$date));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else{
        $code = "login_failed";
        $message = "not found!";
        array_push($response, array("code"=>$code, "messsage"=>$message));
        echo json_encode($response);
        }
    mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Comment: You should loop  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) that statement.

Comment: *this is my PHP code* so why tag this question as Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your table structure, but I think you have to change your code in something like this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
  $response = [];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $response[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
} else{
    $code = "login_failed";
    $message = "not found!";
    array_push($response, array("code"=>$code, "messsage"=>$message));
    echo json_encode($response);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be. Try while loop with result array.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $event = $row["Events"];
    $date = $row["Date"];
    $code = "login_success";
    array_push($response, array("code"=>$code, "Events"=>$event, "Date"=>$date));
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I've answered with a very similar answer 5 seconds after you :P

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is really helpful.